# Skew-symmetric covariant tensor

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors

I read the following and there is something I don't understand about the notation. Why isn't $S_{ij}$ just zero in the below?

> Show that if $T_i$ are the components of covariant tensor $T$, then $S_{ij} = T_i T_j - T_j T_i$ are the components of a skew-symmetric covariant tensor $S$.
>
> The skew-symmetry is obvious. From the transformation law for $T$.
> $$\overline{T}_i \overline{T}_j - \overline{T}_j \overline{T}_i = 
> T_r \frac{\partial x^r}{\partial \overline{x}^i} T_s \frac{\partial x^s}{\partial \overline{x}^j} - T_s \frac{\partial x^s}{\partial \overline{x}^j} T_r \frac{\partial x^r}{\partial \overline{x}^i} = T_r  T_s \frac{\partial x^r}{\partial \overline{x}^i} \frac{\partial x^s}{\partial \overline{x}^j} - T_s  T_r \frac{\partial x^r}{\partial \overline{x}^i} \frac{\partial x^s}{\partial \overline{x}^j}= (T_r  T_s - T_s  T_r) \frac{\partial x^r}{\partial \overline{x}^i} \frac{\partial x^s}{\partial \overline{x}^j}$$
> or
> $$\overline{S}_{ij} = S_{rs} \frac{\partial x^r}{\partial \overline{x}^i} \frac{\partial x^s}{\partial \overline{x}^j}$$
> which establishes the covariant tensor character of $S$.

Comment: Why do you expect that it should be zero?  Do you know that $T_i$ commutes with $T_j$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it *is* zero, but the point of your text is to prove that it indeed is a tensor.

A consequence of this is that if it is zero in one coordinate system ($x^{i}$, say) then it will be zero in every other coordinate system (because of the last expression you wrote).

Comment: So is the point that although its trivial that a tensor stays zero non-tensor objects won't stay zero under change of coordinates.

Comment: Well, the intention of the author might have been (or not) for the readers to understand precisely that. However, it is a fact. A very well known example is the Christoffel symbol $\Gamma$.
Good luck in your reading. :)